# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'l1' was corrupted

Tags: c++

I am currently testing out creating a simple class which sets a number to a private variable, following the last tutorial for deconstructors in this link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm

However, I have been running into this particular issue where it says my variable is corrupted.

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'l1' was corrupted.

This error happens only at the end Training.cpp, when it reaches the last curly bracket.

Here I defined the Line.cpp class alongside the headers.

```
//Line.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Line {

public:

    void setLength(double len);
    double getLength(void);
    Line();

private:

    double length;

};

Line::Line(void){
    cout << "Object is being created." << endl;
}

void Line::setLength(double len) {
    length = len;
}

double Line::getLength(void) {
    return length;
}


// Line.h

#pragma once
#ifndef LINE_H
#define LINE_H

class Line

{
public:
    Line();
    void setLength(double len);
    double getLength(void);
};
#endif LINE_H
```

And Training.cpp calls main function which calls the Line class

```
// Training.cpp

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "Line.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Line l1;
    l1.setLength(10.0);

    cout << "Length of line: " << l1.getLength() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The only difference between the tutorial and my version is that I have extracted the class Line and put it in a class file called Line, which is called by Tranining which has the main function in it.

I have extensively searched for other versions of this error but most of it mentions that it seems to be some form overstepping array boundaries. However I have not assigned any form of char array and am entirely clueless as to why the error is happening. Could any of you help me out on this?

Thanks!

Comment: @François Andrieux, thanks for the formatting help. Stackoverflow wasn't posting my post because of formatting issues so I was trying to post it and edit after.

Comment: It seems like `Line.cpp` and `Line.h` contain two different declarations of class `Line`. That is an ODR violation - Undefined behavior.

Comment: i'm surprised that this thing actually compiles. Anyway, remove `class line {...}` definition from `.cpp` file and move it to the `.h` file, you don't need two, keep the one from .cpp file.

Comment: No errors found. Try rebuild app.

Comment: correct yr code as per @federico and try again

Comment: Following Federico's method, it worked! thanks all for the input :)

Answer (score 2):

You defined twice Line class.
Once in Line.h and another time in Line.cpp.
They also differs (in Line.h it hasn't the member double length; )

Your Line files shoud be like this:

```
//Line.cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
Line::Line(void){
 cout << "Object is being created." << endl;
}
void Line::setLength(double len) {
 length = len;
}
double Line::getLength(void) {
 return length;
}


// Line.h
#pragma once
#ifndef LINE_H
#define LINE_H

class Line
{
public:
  Line();
  void setLength(double len);
  double getLength(void);
private:
  double length;
};
#endif LINE_H
```

Comment: This worked! Just that Line.cpp had to add the include statement for Line.h. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Have followed Federico's answer and the error disappeared. Thanks for the patience!

Just had to add the header file into the Line.cpp and it worked.